# raspberry pi 3 spi issue

Tags: pi-3, python, spi

I connected MOSI to MISO on Raspberry PI 3

Executed the below code:

```
import time
import sys
import spidev


spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
print(spi.bits_per_word)
print(spi.mode)
print(spi.max_speed_hz)
ret = spi.xfer2([0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4])
print (ret)
```

I am getting a different output data than what I send:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/spi $ python3 spi.py 
8
0
125000000
[0, 1, 1, 2]
```

May I know the reason, why is the input data not same as the output?

Update:

> setting the speed to 30 MHZ worked.spi.max_speed_hz = 30000

Comment: From provided data, the only pattern I see it that LSB is missing in data read from. It might be a coincidence. Can you make more experiments, lower the clock perhaps? Which pins are used? Pin configuration?

Comment: I suggest you set a more sensible SPI speed.  I doubt more than 30 MHz works reliably (the current setting is 125 MHz).

Comment: Pins used: 19 and 21 on GPIO Header

Comment: setting the speed to 30 MHZ worked.spi.max_speed_hz = 30000

Comment: @md.jamal Please add this important information to the question's body.